# Change navbar background and navLink color after scrolling in JavaScript with Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

What I'm trying to do is to change the background color of the navbar, as well as the color of the navlink when I'm scrolling, and also change the color of the navlink when I'm hovering over it.

I tried the code more than once but I didn't get any result..

I don't know what the issue is in my code. (I'm using Bootstrap 4 and JavaScript)

**HTML**

```html
<body id="page-top" class="index" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset='0'>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar_style" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container nav_container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top"><span>L</span>OGO</a>
      <a class="navbar-toggler collapsed border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span>
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse div_navbar" id="collapsingNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto text-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#page-top">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#link">link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#explore">explore</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#tours">tours</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">blog</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row header-row">
        <div class="col-md-7 sec-left">
          <div class="info">
            <h2 class="h1 out_Door">Out Door</h2>
            <h2 class="pt-1 happieness">Is Where Life Happieness</h2>
            <p class="pt-2 text-muted">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus exercitationem qui eaque cumque distinctio, Repellendus sit adipisicing elit tenetur minus illo quisquam culpa neque.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 sec-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main data-spy="scroll" data-target="#mainNav">
    <section id='home' class='home'></section>
    <section id='link' class='link'></section>
    <section id='explore' class='explore'></section>
    <section id='tours' class='tours'></section>
    <section id='blog' class='blog'></section>
  </main>
```

**CSS**

```css
.fixed-top {
background-color: red;
transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
.fixed-top.active {background-color:rgba(41,128,185, 0.95) !important;}
.fixed-top ul.navbar-nav li>a {transition: color 1s ease 0s;}
.fixed-top.active ul.navbar-nav li>a {color:black;}
.fixed-top.active ul.navbar-nav li>a:hover {color:#fff;}
.fixed-top ul.navbar-nav li a{color:blueviolet;}
.fixed-top ul.navbar-nav li a:hover{color:deeppink;}
.fixed-top ul.navbar-nav li a:first-child.active{color: yellow;}
.fixed-top ul.navbar-nav li>a.active{
color: #fff;
border-bottom: 3px solid #fec503;
background-color: transparent;   
}
.fixed-top ul.navbar-nav li>a.active:hover,
.fixed-top ul.navbar-nav li>a.active:focus{
color:green;
}
```

**JS code**

```js
var sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
onscroll = function () {
    var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    sections.forEach((section) => {
        if (
            scrollPosition >= section.offsetTop - section.offsetHeight * 0.25 &&
            scrollPosition < section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight - section.offsetHeight * 0.25) {
            var currentId = section.attributes.id.value;
            removeAllActiveClasses();
            addActiveClass(currentId);
        }
    });
};
var removeAllActiveClasses = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-nav a").forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.remove("active");
    });
};
var addActiveClass = function (id) {
    var selector = `nav a[href="#${id}"]`;
    document.querySelector(selector).classList.add("active");
};
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-nav a");
navLinks.forEach((link) => {
link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentId = e.target.attributes.href.value;
    var section = document.querySelector(currentId);
    var sectionPos = section.offsetTop;
});
});
});
```

Comment: I would suggest setting up a code snippet or using a sandbox website to replicate your code. Or at least indenting the code properly, this is quite hard to read imo

Comment: If you could make the code you've added runnable it would be really helpful. The code you've provided isn't directly runnable as-is, it looks partially incomplete.